# How do you import an xPub from a Ledger Nano to a watch only Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, ledger-hardware-wallet

I am having trouble figuring out how to import my xPub from my Ledger Nano to a watch only Full node (Bitcoin Core 0.17.1) Could someone please explain how to do this? I am reading different things. Some people say its not possible on bitcoin core and others offer confusing explainations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Bitcoin Core currently does not support importing extended public keys.

Answer (score 2):

Bitocin Core does not support importing xPub but it does support importing batches of addresses. You can generate a large set of addresses from the xpub (external, change etc.) and import them with one call [`importmulti`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.20.0/rpc/wallet/importmulti/)

Answer (score 0):

You could set up an Electrum Personal Server and import the Master Public key to have a watch only wallet via Electrum and your full node.[Electrum Personal Server Git Hub](https://github.com/chris-belcher/electrum-personal-server)